# job scheduling for a few hours everyday

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, scheduling, jobs

I need to schedule a job starting from 0600 till 1800. The job should run after every two hours. For example 0800, 1000, 1200, 1400, 1600, 1800.

Here is the code I have managed to do so far:

```
DECLARE
     l_id binary_integer;
     begin
       sys.dbms_job.submit(job => l_id, what => 'integration_export;', interval => 'TRUNC(SYSDATE,''hh24'')+0/24/60');
       sys.dbms_output.put_line(l_id);    
end;
```

This will, of course, run the job after every 2 hours without stopping at 1801 - 0759. How may I add this restriction? 
One thing I though is to create another schedule procedure which wakes up at 1801 and changes NEXT_DATE for this job. However, I am wondering if it is a good idea.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Just as a side note, I've worked in a lot of places that like to schedule jobs every x interval, and they always seem to choose "on the hour" exactly, for the sake of tidiness or something. You might find you get better value from your systems by staggering job starts so that they do not all try to start at exactly the same time -- make some 1 minute past, some 2 minutes past, that sort of thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dbms_job` is old. I'd recomend you use the `dbms_scheduler` (introduced in Oracle 10g) instead.

```
dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name        => 'YOUR_JOB',
                          job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK', 
                          job_action      => 'integration_export;',
                          start_date      => systimestamp,
                          repeat_interval => 'freq=hourly; byhour=8,10,12,14,16,18; byminute=0; bysecond=0;',
                      enabled         => true,
                      auto_drop       => false,
                      comments        => 'some comment about the job');
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of dmbs_job, use the advanced dbms_scheduler. Here is an example:

```
begin
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
    job_name        => 'Integration_export',
    job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action      => 'integration_export;',
    start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP,
    enabled         => TRUE,
    repeat_interval => 'freq=daily; byhour=6,8,10,12,14,16,18; byminute=0; bysecond=0');
end;
/
```